# Swift: Is it possible to not reload the first cell/row when using tableView.reloadData()?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reload

I was wondering if it is posible to reload a tableView without reloading the first cell/row in a simple way? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: there is not simple way for this, at leas i don't know how to do it simple

Comment: @ReinierMelian Year, I thought so. I could not find a way either, but just wanted to be sure

Comment: It's easy to do

Comment: @Rob That sounds nice. How would you do it? Maybe you could make an answer?

Comment: I'm posting the solution now

Comment: @Rob Perfect,,,!

Comment: Do you need to reload data in all the sections or just one?

Comment: @Rob Just one in my case

Comment: Actually, I have one more question. What do you have in the first row, and what do you have in the other rows?

Comment: @Rob The reason that I do not want the first row to reload, is that I have a search field in that cell, which need to update everything else than its own cell. Other than that I have some buttons and drop down menus. The others all look the same, except for the text in them. There is also some buttons in them though. Why do you ask?

Comment: It is better If you can add a Screenshot  of UI

Answer (score 2):

```
let itemArray:[Int] = []

for i in 1..<itemArray.count {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

If your table is not grouped currently ,
The best way to do this is add your 1st cell to  one section And all other cells to another section. Then you can easily reload all cell excluding 1st cell using

```
   //section 0 - your 1st cell
   //section 1 - other cells
    tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .none)
```

Comment: Before considering a multi-section approach you'd have to consider if the tableView was gruoped.

Comment: The other problem with calling `reloadRows` multiple times is that the animations are going to look funky. If you are doing multiple updates you should wrap your updates in `begin/endUpdates` or `performBatchUpdates`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the reloadRows method to reload your tableView.

```
var dataSource: [SomeData] = []

func reloadAllButFirstRow() {
    guard dataSource.count > 0 else { return }

    tableView.reloadRows(
        at: (1...dataSource.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) },
        with: .fade
    )
}
```

Comment: I think that your solution works in the way that I asked, but I forgot to mention that the number of rows changes from reload to reload. I thinks it is what causes an error

Comment: @Chris Ok, then you're going to have to show us how you update your data source? How are items added, removed, or modified? Can you post that code?